# Snowflake: Column type changed to FLOAT, but decimal numbers not registering in database

Tags: floating-point, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have some decimal numbers that are being sent to Snowflake. After noticing these numbers weren't registering in the database I looked at the column types and saw they were set to **NUMBER(38,0)** by default. I went ahead and changed their types to **FLOAT** but the data is still not registering.

Is there something I must do in addition to changing the column types to FLOAT?

Also I should mention I have four columns that accept decimal numbers, of the four three were set to NUMBER(38,0) by default and the fourth was set to FLOAT by default. The column set to FLOAT by default has always registered the data correctly.

Comment: How did you change the types of the columns from NUMBER(38,0) to FLOAT, by recreating the table? Snowflake does not allow altering a column from NUMBER to FLOAT or changing the scale of a number. Can you give an example in SQL?

Comment: What is your data source? How is the data being sent to Snowflake? You might try casting to the correct scale before the data is written to Snowflake. For example, if your source is Oracle, note that in Oracle NUMBER can be defined without scale and precision even when it stores decimals and when this is sent to Snowflake, it becomes NUMBER(38,0) and decimals are lost. To overcome this you must cast the NUMBER to the proper scale and precision before writing to Snowflake.

Comment: @GregPavlik I followed the instructions offered by Zaib Zia here: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z000098URJU/sql-compilation-error-cannot-change-column-abc-from-type-number102-to-number112 - Add new column -> Update new column with values of old column -> Drop old column -> Rename new column

Comment: @MajaF. My source is Segment Analytics. I've looked into typcasting on Segment, but it seems Segment produces JSON formatted data to be sent to the destination

Comment: If the data is coming to you as JSON, then somewhere along the way the data is being flattened and cast to a data type before being loaded into your final target table.  If the COPY command or MERGE statements are doing this, there is probably hard-coded casts being done which won't dynamically change just because you change the column data types.  I would look there.

Comment: Please include more code in the question so we can produce an answer with code too

Comment: Did you ever resolve this @mobiman? We are facing a similar issue with Segment -> Snowflake.